# android viewPager implementation

Tags: android

My Task is to make clean scroll right to another screen then press on icon and show popup,
I want to use `ViewPager` to make clean scroll right(swipe) between two pages, and then use `Dialog` to show the popup,
I couldn't find any working sample on how to implement `ViewPager` between two layouts,
someone has working sample??
Thanks.
David

Comment: https://androidbeasts.wordpress.com/2015/08/11/tabs-with-swipe-views/#more-79

Comment: **Simplest way**. I cant answer because question is closed so I posted on Medium-> https://medium.com/@khermaj/android-viewpager-implementation-6c48c868a0e8

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This helped me a lot: http://geekyouup.blogspot.com/2011/07/viewpager-example-from-paug.html

Theres a link to some googlecode you can download and paw through too.

Viewpagers work like list views. To use it with two layouts you're going to have to expand the layouts in a `LayoutInflater` and add as a view to each page.