# sliding effect in activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android Left to Right slide animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5151591/android-left-to-right-slide-animation)

I want to implement sliding (multiple screen which slides) look in activity layout as we have in android home screen. Same type of look in an activity. Kindly prodive with some sugestions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are lookin for ViewPager Implementation. here is a discussion about it.

- [android viewPager implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7244813/603744enter)
- http://geekyouup.blogspot.com/2011/07/viewpager-example-from-paug.html

[ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html) simply looks like a Gallery with one element visibility at a Time. For each page you have to inflate your own layout so that you can customize it with the elements you want.