# How to use Android ViewPager?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [android viewPager implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7244813/android-viewpager-implementation)

Can someone please tell me how I can properly implement ViewPager into my project? I need to know what I can achieve by using it?
I am somewhat new to programming and android. Basically I need to use horizontal paging for an app on which I am working on right now.

I need step by step instruction guide for this.

Comment: duplication of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7244813/android-viewpager-implementation

Comment: https://androidbeasts.wordpress.com/2015/08/11/tabs-with-swipe-views/#more-79

Comment: **Simplest way**. I cant answer because question is closed so I posted on Medium-> https://medium.com/@khermaj/android-viewpager-implementation-6c48c868a0e8

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this site - [Page swiping using ViewPager](http://thepseudocoder.wordpress.com/2011/10/05/android-page-swiping-using-viewpager/)

This will help you to implement view pager step by step.

[ViewPager Example](http://manishkpr.webheavens.com/android-viewpager-example/)

Answer (score 1):

It's done automatically with the new ADT 20, you just need to choose "tabs+swipe" in the right section when you create a new Android application.
Then you'll just have to create fragments, like the Dummy one they gave you for example.