# Android gallery of drawables

Tags: android, image, gallery, out-of-memory, recycle

I'm creating a simple `Gallery` of drawables - each of them is almost the size of a screen, so they require quite much memory. For each entry I'm creating a custom `LinearLayout` with `ImageView` and `TextView` for the title. As most of you know, android `Gallery` doesn't recycle views so it gallery will crash easily on low-memory phones (after loading 4 drawables on 16mb ram limit, in my case).

Here's the simple question - how do you implement such gallery, so it won't run out of the memory? How do you recycle these images? A working code example would be great.

Few notes:

- inSampleSize isn't a way to go, I can't scale these images down
- Calling recycle() on Drawable's loaded from resource is impossible, as it will crash on Android 4.0+ (it will recycle the drawable in their internal cache)
- Don't ask me to post the code, as there is no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't be using Gallery because it's deprecated. Especially since there isn't any code written so far. The documentation suggests using a HorizontalScrollView or ViewPager.

I feel a ViewPager is what your looking for because it will only keep at most 3 pictures in memory and handels all the recycling for you. Here is a post with more information about how to implement one [android viewPager implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7244813/android-viewpager-implementation)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. ViewPager won't work for me, as I need part of the neighboor images to be visible too. I guess I'll just have to go with HorizontalScrollView.

Comment: Ahh. Yes. I would check out the code for the People application introduced in 4.0. When you view a ContactDetails your able to see some of their status on the right and then when you swipe you it scrolls and snaps. This was down with a HSV plus some snapping logic.