# How to set the layout of a ViewPager page?

Tags: android

I have two tabs on my ActionBar and four pages in a ViewPager. I need to define and specify eight different layouts for these situations.
I've written the XML layouts, but where do I set them?

Comment: in the java code. there is a addView method

Comment: [Linked Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7244813/android-viewpager-implementation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's are some nice tutorials you can use:

http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/08/horizontal-view-swiping-with-viewpager.html

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-user-interface-design-horizontal-view-paging/

https://thepseudocoder.wordpress.com/2011/10/05/android-page-swiping-using-viewpager/