# Android swipe left and right from record to record

Tags: android

A lot of apps that I have (such as gmail) has a feature where you can swipe left and right to go from one record to another. In gmail, this navigation takes you from one email to the next (or previous, depending on which way you swipe). When you reach the end, you get this blue halo effect, and the swiping in that direction doesn't work. My question is, what is this navigation called? Is it something in the sdk, or is it written by the developer for each app? Can I use it in my app where I have data stored in the sqlite database that I would like to show one record at a time this way? Is it available in all sdk versions?

I would search for it, but I don't know what it's called so I can't really think of any good search terms here. If someone just points me in the right direction, I can read the documentation and figure it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The component you are looking for calls `ViewPager.` You'll find in under the compatibility pack jar.

[android viewPager implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7244813/android-viewpager-implementation)

http://android-developers.blogspot.co.il/2011/08/horizontal-view-swiping-with-viewpager.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use something called a viewFlipper if you want to use animations.

There's a nice tutorial here: http://www.warriorpoint.com/blog/2009/05/26/android-switching-screens-in-an-activity-with-animations-using-viewflipper/

Good luck :)