# best way to manage paging(swipe views) for single form fields?

Tags: android, android-lazyadapter

I have more details for one form in android. I dont want to add scrollview because of the design limitation. Now i want to load the views on swipe(there are total 5 pages within single form). what is the best option to achieve this?
take one xml layout and hide/show different views on swipe??

Answer (score 1):

I think [ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html) will be best. It's also available in [compatibility package](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html) for backward compatibility.

check this for [android viewpager implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7244813/android-viewpager-implementation)